# $f(x) \geq g(x) \Leftarrow \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}=0 $?

Tags: limits, functions, computer-science

I want to know if function $f(x)$ is greater or equal than $g(x)$. If I prove that

$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}=0$ then is it so?

Comment: How can two functions be compared are you talking about graphs

Comment: No; $x+1 \ge x$ but $\frac{x}{x+1} \to \ldots (\ne 0)$

Comment: @StackTD Thanks for answering. I just wanted to use it to be able to apply the Squeeze theorem

Comment: Your question is not very clear, do you want an equivalence (as in your title) or only the implication $\lim_{x\to \infty }\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}=0\Rightarrow f(x)\geq g(x)$ (which is what you ask for in the question)?

Comment: You're right! I will edit it

Answer (score 2):

This is certainly not an "$\Leftrightarrow$", for example $f(x)=g(x)=1$ leds to $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}=1$.

We *do* have the following related results:

- If $f(x)\ge g(x)>0$ for all $x$ (or just for all $x>x_0$) then $\limsup _{x\to\infty}\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}\le1$
- If $\left|\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}\right|<1$ then there exists $x_0$ such that $|f(x)|\ge |g(x)|$ for all $x>x_0$

Comment: Thanks for answering! If there exists $x_0$ such that $|f(x)|\ge |g(x)|$ for all $x>x_0$ is it sufficient to use the squeeze theorem?

Answer (score 1):

If
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}=0,
$$
then we have that for any $\varepsilon>0$
$$
\biggl|\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}\biggr|<\varepsilon
$$
when $x>x_0$ for some $x_0\in\mathbb R$. Set $\varepsilon=1$. Then we obtain
$$
\biggl|\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}\biggr|<1
$$
or
$$
|g(x)|<|f(x)|
$$
when $x>x_0$ for some $x_0\in\mathbb R$. Hence, function $|f(x)|$ is greater than $|g(x)|$ when $x$ is sufficiently large. However, it does not hold in the opposite direction as noted in the comments.

Comment: Which definition of limit are you using? It seems the $\epsilon$-definition but for sequences...

Comment: @JellyBelly [This definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Limits_at_infinity).